# Opening a URL from Flash using navigateToURL (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, url, hyperlink, navigatetourl

Been pulling my hair out for hours today over this.
I can't open another website from my already opened flash site.

Here is the code:

```
GotoFB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoFB);

function gotoFB(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.facebook.com"), "_blank");
}
```

This works from the flash player but not from chrome/ie/firefox..

Comment: What you mean you can't open it? Do you have any error message?

Comment: It works _PERFECTLY_ from a browser too. Also what @Sr.Richie said

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. ([faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures))

Comment: Can you get a link to the same site the Flash is on to work? What addons / plugins do you have in your browser? What does your html look like? Can you get it to work on someone else's computer?

Answer (score 6):

Had some problems with navigateToUrl in recent chrome-update in my Flex-app. Had to use this workaround:

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.open", url, target);
```

Comment: Hello, 

Have you been able to resolved this problem. I am getting same. Please let me know if you have a solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: I used ExternalInterface.

Comment: What is `target` here?

Comment: @Peanut The target would be "_blank" if using the OP's example

Answer (score 0):

Some popup blockers blocks `navigateToURL(..., "_blank")`, there is a bunch of workarounds of varying quality out there, mainly involving calling JavaScript's `window.open` via `ExternalInterface` instead of using `navigateToURL(..., "_blank")`. If you google for it, you may find one that works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

File->Publish Settings->Local playback security->Access network only

Voila...